# converting my code from cpp to python giving me wrong results

Tags: python

i am trying to convert my code from cpp to python
what the code does is reads a 2d array divides into equal parts of w*w and calculates the average of the values of all the entries in the w*w part and stores it in another array 
the code  is working fine in cpp but when i write almost similar code in python its giving wrong results 
my cpp code is '

```
for (int h=0,r=0;h<HEIGHT;r=0,h+=w)
{
    for (;r<WIDTH;r+=w)
    {
        for (int i=h;i<h+w;i++)
        {
            for (int j=r;j<r+w;j++)
            {
                averageImArray[h/w][r/w]+=imArray[i][j];
            }
        }
        averageImArray[h/w][r/w]/=w*w;
    }
}
```

and the corresponding python code is

```
h=0
r=0
while (h<height):
    while (r<width):
        i=h
        while (i<h+w):
            j=r
            while (j<r+w):
                averageImArray[h/w][r/w]+=imArray[i][j]
                j+=1
            averageImArray[h/w][r/w]=(averageImArray[h/w][r/w])/(w*w)
            i+=1
        r+=w
    r=0
    h+=w
```

can someone please highlight the error

Comment: while != for (;;).  Try to use in Python 'for h in range(HEIGHT):'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python control blocks are controlled by indentation.

In your c++ code, `averageImArray[h/w][r/w]/=w*w;` is part of the second loop.
While in your python code, it's part of the third loop.

Essentially, it's not the same algorithm. You probably got confused because you attempted to directly write C++ code in Python. Not only is it not the Pythonic way to write code, it'll be less efficient and more error prone. I suggest you rewrite your code with Pythons `for` syntax for one:

```
for h in range(0, height, w): #for python 2.x it should be xrange
    for r in range(0 , width, w):
        for i in range(h, h+w):
            for j in range(r, r+w):
                averageImArray[h/w][r/w]+=imArray[i][j]
        averageImArray[h/w][r/w]=(averageImArray[h/w][r/w])/(w*w)
```

The boiler plate is now gone, and it's a bit more obvious what code belongs where. The next step is to eliminate the deeply nested loops. The two innermost ones belong in a separate function.